# Is there an official folder in the home directory for storing keymaps?

Tags: keyboard, home-directory, xkb

I can add a custom xkb keyboard layout in
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols
and acrivate it using `setxkbmap`.

The downside of storing data in this system folder is that it gets lost when `xkb-data` is reinstalled or updated.

Is there a folder in the home directory where I can permanently store custom keymaps for xkb?

Comment: Why not just backup the layout. `xkb-data` is normally only updated when you upgrade to a new Ubuntu release.

Comment: creatign a layout folder in my user dir and (r)syncing to the /usr dir is my current approach.  am just not comfortable with it. I will also not place my binaries for example in /usr/bin. Why mess with the folder structure when there are /usr/local/ and ~/.local for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's is a limitation of XKB which can't be easily worked around. There is a fresh [Ubuntu bug report](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1738630) which highlights the issue, but a possible fix should reasonably be done upstream. Can't tell if/when it will happen.

It's worth mentioning that for this very reason we usually don't update `xkb-data` in stable releases.

Comment: I haven’t tried this yet, but does the info in https://www.vinc17.net/unix/xkb.en.html (in a user-specific X startup file, use `xkbcomp` to load custom configuration from the home directory) not work?

Comment: @DanielH: Possibly. But I wouldn't consider it to be very easy. ;)